# OGRE 1.6.1 License

Tags: licensing, ogre3d

Does anybody know whether I can use the resources supplied by OGRE 1.6.1 in a paper I publish in academia? Could you please refer me to some official links to feel relaxed? :-)

Thanks,
Rafid

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2):

> OGRE (www.ogre3d.org) is made
>   available under the MIT License.
>
> Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Torus Knot
>   Software Ltd
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated
>   documentation files (the "Software"),
>   to deal in the Software without
>   restriction, including without
>   limitation the rights to use, copy,
>   modify, merge, publish, distribute,
>   sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
>   Software, and to permit persons to
>   whom the Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
>   permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of
>   the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS",
>   WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
>   OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE
>   FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
>   CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
>   FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
>   IN THE SOFTWARE.

Licensing FAQ: http://www.ogre3d.org/licensing/licensing-faq

License: http://ogre.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ogre/trunk/COPYING?revision=9087

Their support forum where to ask for a concrete answer: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/

Comment: Wasn't ogre 1.6.1 released under the LGPL? Most of the Media Media Files should be the same in Ogre 1.7 (which is unter the MIT license).